# Run different code in VS designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a class that inherits the Windows Forms Combobox.
The class should do extra work when items are added, but there is no such event.
Therefore, I have added methods to add and clear items, which do the extra work.
To avoid developers accessing the Items directly and adding to them, I have overloaded the Items property to throw an exception.

This all works fine, except in the VS designer. The designer tries to access the Items property, gets the exception and shows an error.

Is there a defined constant for when the VS designer compiles the code? This seems like it would be best suited to the task.

Comment: Do you mean *shadowed* when you say you've *overloaded* the `Items` property?

Comment: This is vb.net so _shadow_ is _overload_

Comment: No, they're not the same thing. Overloading is providing a new member with the same name but a *different signature* (usually for methods). Shadowing is providing a new member with the *same* signature as an existing one, but not overriding the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`Control.DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property? To be honest, it doesn't sound great from a design point of view to have a `ComboBox` subclass which can't be used as a normal `ComboBox`... and if you've really just *hidden* (or shadowed) the `Items` property with another one, then anyone referring to it *as* a `ComboBox` will have access to the original `Items` property anyway. It's unclear what you're *really* trying to do here.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have a combobox where I can do extra work when items are added to it. If there was such an event, I would have no need for this.

Yes, anyone who refers to it as a combobox will be able to circumvent this. However, no one has any reason to refer to it as a combobox, unless they are intentionally trying to do mischief. The form's member is an instance of the inheriting class.

I'm aware that this isn't ideal, but I am trying to find something that will work in most cases, without developers forgetting that they can't use the Items property.

Comment: You could write a custom `Designer` for your inherited component to gain control on what can be done in desig mode.